# Get terms from node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I need to get the terms a node has. I found out that you can use this:

```
$result = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags', array('default'));
```

But this prints a rendered list. I need the names, or tids.

How do I separate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with taxonomy_node_get_terms() function (D6) you can get 'terms from node'. one example:

```
<?php
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);// get term from nodes
rsort($terms); //rsort() just sort an array in reverse order
$myterm = $terms[0]->name; //get a value
echo $myterm; //show value
?>
```

Comment: -1 Works only for DP6

Answer (score 1):

Searching on api.drupal.org I see there is a `field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tags');`that you could use.

You can also inspect the $node object and get the values directly from there. To inspect the `$node` object I recommend you install the devel module and then use the dpm or krumo function like:

```
krumo($node);
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a taxonomy field in a node is similar to the following one:

[image: screenshot]

The first array index is the identifier of the language associated with the taxonomy, or "und" (the value of the constant [LANGUAGE_NONE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7)) if the taxonomy term doesn't have any associated language.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working:

```
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);
$i = 0;

foreach ($terms as $term){ 

    $tid = $term->tid;

    $name = $term->name;

    // show the terms

    print $name.'<br>';

}
```